# How to pass parameter n to printf("%nd", some_int);

Tags: c, linux, format

We all know in C-based languages, **printf("%11d", some_int);**  means right align within an 11 character field, but what if I want to replace this constant 11 here with a dynamic variable, what am I gonna do ?

Comment: man pages can be good friends :)

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `*` character to specify the field width in its own argument:

```
printf("%*d", some_width, some_int);
```

Comment: note: the width argument must have type `int`, so you usually will want to use a cast to ensure this

Answer (score 6):

You are going to read the `printf(3)` man page and come across the following:

> Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some  decimal  integer
>          m) to specify that the field width is given in the next argument, or in
>          the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of type int.

Answer (score 2):

use linux command: "man 3 printf" to get more information.
One way to do this is

```
 printf("%*d", width, num);
```

where width is precision and num is argument to print.
Other way equivalent to above one is

```
 printf("%2$*1$d", width, num);
```

More generally this is written as "*m$d", where m is int and argument number.

Comment: The second option is not in ISO C  (I think it's a POSIX extension)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to use an snprintf-equivalent on a character array buffer, in order to create your printf format string.  (Be sure to check for buffer overflows, of course.)

Comment: Oops, Frédéric's answer is better than mine.