# Variable Print Formatting [C]

Tags: c

I know that

```
printf("%.10s", "Hello, world!");
```

will only print 10 characters. The output of that instruction is "Hello, wor". I want to know if there is a way for a variable to control how many characters will be printed.

Example:

```
printf("%.[size]s", "Hello, world!");
```

Where [size] is the maximum amount of characters to be printed.

Comment: [How to pass parameter n to printf(“%nd”, some_int);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887979/how-to-pass-parameter-n-to-printfnd-some-int) - probably this will help

Comment: Also as a general bit of advise, it is time will taken when you are learning C to spend the time it takes to read the manual (or `man`) pages for the `printf` and `scanf` family of functions (in detail). There are many subtleties contained in them that can (1) help you with your programming and *more importantly* (2) help you avoid a number of pitfalls that await the unaware.

Comment: A short search for "printf format string" would have been easier.

Answer (score 3):

Posted this in the question, but I should close the question as well.

**SOLUTION**

I actually found the answer as I was asking this, but I wanted to put it up for others anyway. The correct format would be to use * where [size] is.

```
int size = 10;
printf("%.*s\n", size, "Hello, world");
```